# Obtaining analog video from car LVDS interface theoretical question

Tags: automotive, video, lvds

Got a theoretical question.

A car has 4(5 with GND) pin FAKRA connector between head unit (NAC) and head display. 2 of them are mentioned as LVDS+ and LVDS-.

As far as I understand, it's 2-way gigabit LVDS, because touch commands get back to the head unit within the same data contacts.

The chip used by the display unit is Maxim MAX9260GCB/V.

**Question is**: is there any way to obtain an analog video at any level after the display unit? Maybe from FPC screen output?

Here on Stackexchange I found an example of RTD2662 usage, but I need digital->analog.

NOTE: I know this is a generalized question and I do not expect the exact solution right away. It's more about if this is possible without developing a custom PCB solution for that.

Comment: Is it possible in any way in theory? Yes. It is possible to convert digital video to analog. You might describe what kind of analog video interface you mean? VGA, YPbPr, Y/C, Composite, etc? In practice, it may be so hard it is impossible, depending on what you expect.